# C-x k does not kill a buffer in mac emacs

Tags: macos, emacs

I have been using emacs in mac from this repo https://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit  it helped me get started easily. But the problem, is whenever i try to kill a buffer using `C-x k` it hides the file from the buffer, but it still remains available. When i do `C-x b` i can see it again, to select from.

Whats wrong with it?

Does ispell has to do anything with it? 
But i have already installed ispell using `brew install ispell`

Please let me know how do i fix this. Thanks!

As asked below, showing what C-x k is bound to, here is the output:

```
C-x k runs the command ido-kill-buffer, which is an interactive
compiled Lisp function in `ido.el'.

It is bound to C-x k.

(ido-kill-buffer)

Kill a buffer.
The buffer name is selected interactively by typing a substring.
For details of keybindings, see `ido-switch-buffer'.
```

Comment: What does `M-x describe-key` say `C-x k` is bound to?

Comment: Does the same happen when you start Emacs with the `-q` command-line argument?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because starter-kit sets `ido-use-virtual-buffers` to t.
The buffer is actually killed, but it's displayed by ido anyway, as part of the recently used ones, and can be revived quickly.

If you don't like it, just

```
(setq ido-use-virtual-buffers nil)
```